# how to list categories and unlimited depth of categories?

Tags: php, mysqli

My **mysqli** class is here. https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

I created **categories** table like :

[image]

### Some notes.

**If the row cat_parent == 0 it means top level category.**

Also, cat_status == 0 that item, must be in the tree.

Now, i want to list them like a category tree ?
Or want to use in select box with depth.

Could anyone give me an example please.

### NOTE

Also tried this advice http://forums.codewalkers.com/php-coding-7/unlimited-infinite-levels-depths-of-categories-with-php-and-mysql-1087307.html but someone said this is worst coding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have already done.

Here is the result.

```
function __getCats($cat_parent=0) {
    global $db;
    $cats = $db->get('categories');
    if ($cats>0) {
        $list_items = array();
        foreach ( $cats as $cat )
        {
            if ( ( int ) $cat['cat_parent'] !== ( int ) $cat_parent )
            {
                continue;
            }
            $list_items[] = '<li>';
            $list_items[] = '<a href="#' . $cat['id'] . '">';
            $list_items[] = $cat['cat_name'];
            $list_items[] = '</a>';
            $list_items[] = __getCats( $cat['id'] );
            $list_items[] = '</li>';

        }
        $list_items = implode( '', $list_items );
        if ( '' == trim( $list_items ) )
        {
            return '';
        }
        return '<ul>' . $list_items . '</ul>';
    }
}
```